# What is the difference between @BeforeClass and Spring @TestExecutionListener beforeTestClass()

Tags: junit4, spring-test

What is the difference between using JUnit @BeforeClass and the Spring @TestExecutionListener beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) "hook"?  If there is a difference, which one to use under which circumstances?

Maven Dependencies:
spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE 
spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE  
spring-test:3.0.6.RELEASE  
spring-data-commons-core:1.2.0.M1  
spring-data-mongodb:1.0.0.M4  
mongo-java-driver:2.7.3  
junit:4.9 
cglib:2.2

### Using JUnit @BeforeClass annotation:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-config.xml" })
public class TestNothing extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void runBefore() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass: set up.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testInit() {
        Assert.assertTrue(repo.findAll().size() == 0 );
    }
}

=> @BeforeClass: set up.
=> Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Using the Spring hook:

(1) Override beforeTestClass(TextContext testContext):

```
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener;

public class BeforeClassHook extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    public BeforeClassHook() { }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        System.out.println("BeforeClassHook.beforeTestClass(): set up.");
    }
}
```

(2) Use @TestExecutionListeners annotation:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;  
// other imports are the same    

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-config.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners(BeforeClassHook.class)
public class TestNothing extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void testInit() {
        Assert.assertTrue(repo.findAll().size() == 0 );
    }
}

=> BeforeClassHook.beforeTestClass(): set up.
=> Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`TestExecutionListeners` are a way to externalize reusable code that *instruments* your tests.

As such, if you implement a `TestExecutionListener` you can reuse it across test class hierarchies and potentially across projects, depending on your needs.

On the flip side, a `@BeforeClass` method can naturally only be used within a single test class hierarchy.

Note, however, that JUnit also supports [Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules): if you implement `org.junit.rules.TestRule` you can declare it as a `@ClassRule` to achieve the same thing... with the added benefit that a JUnit Rule can be reused just like a Spring `TestExecutionListener`.

So it really depends on your use case. If you only need to use the "before class" functionality in a single test class or a single test class hierarchy, then you'd be better off going the simple route of just implementing a `@BeforeClass` method. However, if you foresee that you will need the "before class" functionality in different test class hierarchies or across projects, you should consider implementing a custom `TestExecutionListener` or JUnit Rule.

The benefit of a Spring `TestExecutionListener` over a JUnit Rule is that a `TestExecutionListener` has access to the `TestContext` and therefore access to the Spring `ApplicationContext` which a JUnit Rule would not have access to. Furthermore, a `TestExecutionListener` can be [automatically discovered](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery) and [ordered](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-ordering).

*Related Resources*:

- [SPR-8854](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8854)

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: Is there any way to set the order of the listeners? (E.g. I want to run some code before the loading of the spring context happens)

Comment: Yes, you can control the order of the listeners when you declare `@TestExecutionListeners` on your test class. See slides 27-33 in my [Spring 3.1 and MVC Testing Support](http://www.slideshare.net/sbrannen/spring-31-and-mvc-testing-support) presentation, and consult the Javadoc for [@TestExecutionListeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListeners.html).

Comment: Just read up on both references, but I don't see anything related to the order. Are they supposed to run in the order you declare them on the annotation?

Comment: Yes, the `TestContextManager` maintains them as `List<TestExecutionListener> testExecutionListeners`, which is an ordered list that is constructed based on the order in which the listeners are declared via `@TestExecutionListeners`.

Comment: And what if you use inheritance of listeners?

Comment: Please consult the Javadoc for [@TestExecutionListeners#inheritListeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListeners.html#inheritListeners--).

Answer (score 2):

The first solution with @BeforeClass doesn't have application context loaded. I did exteneded AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests and defined @ContextConfiguration.
I think listner is the only way to get context loaded before @beforeclass method. Or even better extending SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class as mentioned [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/enhancing-spring-test)